# Displaying Data from MySQL database with PHP in a table and making it editable

Tags: php, mysql

I need help getting my database table to show on to my php page. Does anyone have suggetions they can help me with? I know this might be a repeat of a previous question but any help is greatly appreciated. I got the data to display but now I can't get to be in a table format any suggestions?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Music Database</title>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Music List Storage</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <header><h1><center>Music Playlist for Month 1</center></header>

    <?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'music_database');

    if(!$con)
    {
        die("Can not connect: " . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con, 'music_database'))
    {
        echo 'Database Not Selected!';
    }


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM month1";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if (!$query) 
    { // add this check.
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    } else{




    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th>Song Title</th>
    <th>Song Artist</th>
    <th>Song Album</th>
    <th>Year Released</th>
    <th>Month Played</th>
    <th>Day of the Week Played</th>
    <th>Date Played</th>
    <th>Time Played</th>
    </tr>";




      while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
      {
        echo "<tr>";
            var_dump($record);
        echo "</tr>";

      }

    } 
     mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

    </table>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Music List Storage</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <header><h1><center>Music Playlist for Month 1</center></header>

    <?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'music_database');

    if(!$con)
    {
        die("Can not connect: " . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con, 'music_database'))
    {
        echo 'Database Not Selected!';
    }


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM month1";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if (!$query) 
    { // add this check.
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    } else{




    echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th>Song Title</th>
    <th>Song Artist</th>
    <th>Song Album</th>
    <th>Year Released</th>
    <th>Month Played</th>
    <th>Day of the Week Played</th>
    <th>Date Played</th>
    <th>Time Played</th>
    </tr>";




      while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
      {
        echo "<tr>";
            var_dump($record);
        echo "</tr>";

      }

    } 
     mysqli_close($con);
    ?>

    </table>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129601/discussion-on-question-by-brett-muldrow-displaying-data-from-mysql-database-with).

Comment: Does anyone know how to fix Notice: Undefined index: songtitle in C:\wamp64\www\showrecords.php on line 64? It goes on for 7 more like this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the $con variable to mysqli_error()
like this, it expects connection variable

```
if(!$con)
{
    die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error($con));
}
```

also, if you want them to be editable, then simple change your while loop like this:

```
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type='text' value='" . $record['songtitle'] . "'/>". "</td>";
    .
    .
    echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Can someone help me with var_dump and where it should go?

Comment: what are you testing with var_dump? which variable basically?

Comment: I'm trying to display the all data in the columns from a phpMyAdmin Database table in a table on a php page.

Comment: var_dump, would come after this, like

$record = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
var_dump($record);

Comment: Would that be inside the parentheses?

Comment: Also now I'm having problems having the data show up in table format any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

use this code formet

```
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {
        echo "<tr>
              <td>'.$record['title'].'</td>
              <td>'.$record['Album'].'</td>
              <td>'.$record['Year '].'</td>
              <td>.'$record['Month'].'</td>
              <td>'.$record['Day'].'</td>
              <td>'.$record['Date'].'</td>
              <td>'.$record['Time '].'</td>
        </tr>";
  }
```

Comment: I have another question I want to create a button that can randomize this table in php. Any ideas?